# Pineapple leaf discoloration?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, diseases, leaves, plant-care

Can some tell me what’s going on with my plant? I have not done anything different and this started when we moved it inside.

[image]

Comment: When you say pineapple leaf, do you mean a true pineapple, an Ananas variety? Only they usually have serrated edges to the leaves, and the leaves in your image do not... It might be useful to see another photo showing the whole plant as well as this closeup, if you can add one. What part of the world  are you in?